# How to put a dropdown under figure title?

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly-dash, plotly-python

I'm trying to learn dash because that's the tool that we will be using in a new project.

The thing is that searching through things I needed I learned how to update a figure data using a dropdown, but the dropdown position is not the one I desire.

```
import dash
import dash_table

import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html

from dash.dependencies import Input, Output

import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go

import pickle

import os

import datetime

dirname = os.path.dirname(__file__)

dash_app = dash.Dash(__name__, routes_pathname_prefix='/')

###########   DATA   ###########

with open( os.path.join(dirname, "pickle_data", 'hashtag_statistics.pickle'), 'rb') as f:
    hashtag_statistics = pickle.load(f)

#################     APP LAYOUT DEF     #################

dash_app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Dropdown(
        id='dropdown-programas-social',
        value='XXX',
        options=[{'value': x, 'label': x} for x in hashtag_statistics],
        clearable=False,
        style={
            'width': '50%',
            'margin-left': '25%'
        } 
    ),
    dcc.Graph(
        id='graphics',
        style={
            'height': 700
        }
    )
],
className='dropdown-div',
style={
        'background-color': 'white'
}
)

###############    CALLBACK    ###############

@dash_app.callback(
    [Output('graphics', 'figure'),
    Input('dropdown-programas-social', 'value')])
def update_pie(dropdown_values):

    fig = px.pie(hashtag_statistics, values=hashtag_statistics[dropdown_values].values(), 
                  names=hashtag_statistics[dropdown_values].keys(), title='Utilización de hashtags según el programa seleccionado', hole=0.2)


    return [fig]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    dash_app.run_server(debug=True)
```

[image: As you can see, the dropdown is on top of the title of the figure]

I understand that the figure has its own title and I don't know if this is doable, but I'd like to have the dropdown under the title of the figure as if it was inside to add clarity.

If this is not doable, I'd like to add the title as HTML or something on top of the dropdown, but I could not find the style of Plotly Figure titles.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure - since the piechart is a figure - and the title is part of that figure.
However - you could use this figure as a background image of the page.
See here:
https://community.plotly.com/t/add-background-image-to-html-div/12453/3